Indices imply "Type of tensor" for a basis transformation matrix
I'm reading Liang's book on Differential Geometry, and came across this part:

If there is a basis transformation $e'_j=A^i_{\ \ j}e_i$ in a vector space $V$ and the (non-degenerate) matrix constituted by elements $A^i_{\ \ j}$ is denoted by $A$, then the corresponding dual basis transformation is $$\epsilon'^j=(\tilde A^{-1})_i^{\ \ \ j}\epsilon^i$$ where $\tilde A=A^T$ (transpose)


Remark: Here we write the matrix elements as $A^i_{\ \ j}$. The reason for distinguishing the upper and lower indices is to distinguish summation and to distinguish the type of a tensor. However, what is important in the matrix operation is just differentiating the left and right indices. Therefore, if you want, you may change all upper indices to lower indices for now; for instance the last equation can be written as $\epsilon'_j=(\tilde A^{-1})_{ij}\epsilon_i$.

I just want to have a crystal clear understanding of why this notation is chosen. Basis transformation would be an automorphism from $V$ to $V$, and there's a result saying that the set of automorphisms is isomorphic to $T_1^1(V)$. So $A$ can be identified with a tensor that eats a covector and a vector => so its index representation (i.e. element indexing) is to be identified with some $(1,1)$ tensor $T$, i.e. $T^i_{\ \ j}=T(\epsilon^i,e_j)$. So we also represent $A$ by $A^i_{\ \ j}$.
But I'm confused why we're writing staggered index notation for $(\tilde A^{-1})$ as $(\tilde A^{-1})_i^{\ \ \ j}$ - is there some concrete reason? Should I imagine $(\tilde A^{-1})$ as some automorphism from $V^*$ to $V^*$, and using similar logic as before, say that it can be identified with some tensor $\tilde T\in T^1_1(V^*)$? In that case, elements of $\tilde T$ are represented as $\tilde T(e'_i,\epsilon'^j)=\tilde T_i^{\ \ \ j}$, so we represent $(\tilde A^{-1})$ by $(\tilde A^{-1})_i^{\ \ \ j}$?

Start with a vector space $V$ and basis vectors $e_i$. For any vector $v \in V$ we can write,
$$
v = v^i e_i
$$
$\def\F{\mathbb{F}}$
A second-order mixed tensor $A$ is a map $A: V^* \times V \rightarrow \F$ where $V^*$ is the dual space of $V$ and $\F$ is the field over which $V$ is defined; the same map can be used to construct,

A map $V \rightarrow V$ using $A(-,v)$.
A map $V^* \rightarrow V^*$ using $A(v^*,-)$ ($v^*$ denotes a covector).

For example, given a basis vector $e_i$ we can use this bilinear map to write,
$$
\def\te{{\tilde e}}
\te_i = A(-,e_i)={A^k}_l e_k \otimes e^l (-,e_i)={A^k}_l e_k e^l(e_i) = {A^k}_l e_k \delta^l_i = {A^k}_i e_k
$$
which is a passive transformation (if $A$ is nondegenerate) from one basis to another ($e^i$ is a basis vector of $V^*$). Since,
$$
\def\tv{{\tilde v}}
v = \tv^i \te_i = \tv^i  {A^k}_i e_k = v^k e_k
$$
we obtain the contravariant transformation:
$$
\def\inv#1{{\overline #1}}
v^k = {A^k}_i \tv^i \implies \tv^i = {\inv{A}^i}_k  v^k
$$
where $\inv{A}$ denotes the inverse of $A$. Note that the definition of the inverse requires that,
$$
{\inv{A}}(-,A(-,v))=Iv
$$
where $I$ is the identity map. From this definition we have,
$$
{\inv{A}^j}_i e_j \otimes e^i(A(-,v))
=
{\inv{A}^j}_i e_j e^i(A(-,v))
$$
Since,
$$
A(-,v) = {A^l}_k e_l \otimes e^k (-,v) = {A^l}_k e_l e^k(v^m e_m)
= {A^l}_k e_l v^m e^k( e_m) = {A^l}_k e_l v^m \delta^k_m
= {A^l}_k e_l v^k 
$$
we can now write,
$$
{\inv{A}}(-,A(-,v))={\inv{A}^j}_i e_j e^i({A^l}_k v^k e_l )
={\inv{A}^j}_i e_j {A^l}_k v^k e^i(e_l)
= {\inv{A}^j}_i e_j {A^l}_k v^k \delta^i_l
= v^k {\inv{A}^j}_i {A^i}_k e_j 
$$
This expression should be equal to $v^k e_k$ so we must have,
$$
{\inv{A}^j}_i {A^i}_k =\delta^j_k
$$
which is the equation that defines the components of the inverse tensor.
Lets denote the tensor for the passive transformation from $e^k$ to $\te^j$ as $B$. Given a basis vector $e^k$ of $V^*$ we have,
$$
\te^k = B(e^k,-)={B^q}_p e_q \otimes e^p (e^k,-) =  {B^q}_p e^k(e_q) e^p = {B^q}_p \delta^k_q e^p = {B^k}_p e^p 
$$
Since $\te^k(\te_l)=\delta^k_l$,
$$
\te^k(\te_l) = {B^k}_p e^p ({A^r}_l e_r) = {B^k}_p  {A^r}_l e^p(e_r)
= {B^k}_p  {A^r}_l \delta^p_r = {B^k}_p  {A^p}_l = \delta^k_l
$$
and so $B \equiv \inv{A}$. So we must have,
$$
\te^k = {\inv{A}^k}_p e^p
$$
Since any covector $v^*$ has the following expansion,
$$
v^* = v_k e^k =  \tv_p \te^p = \tv_p  {\inv{A}^p}_k e^k
$$
we have,
$$
v_k = \tv_p  {\inv{A}^p}_k \implies \tv_p = {A^k}_p v_k
$$
which is a covariant transformation.

Recommendation: Start from
\begin{align}
e'_j&=A^i{}_j\,e_i\,,\quad\text{(covariant transformation)}&e_i\,\epsilon^i&=e'_j\,\epsilon'^j\quad\text{(scalar is invariant)}
\end{align}
to conclude that
\begin{align}\tag1
\epsilon'^j&=A_k{}^j\,\epsilon^k\,,&A^i{}_j\,A_k{}^j=\delta^i{}_k
\end{align}
must hold which tells us what second order tensor is the matrix inverse of $A^i{}_j\,:$

it is the transpose of $A_k{}^j\,.$

Imho fiddling around with transposes and matrix inverse notation from linear algebra does not make index notation any clearer.
It just adds confusion.
Edit: If we wanted to write instead
$$
\epsilon'^j=A^j{}_k\,\epsilon^k
$$
and plug that in we get
\begin{align}
e'_j\,\epsilon'^j&=A^i{}_j\,A^j{}_k\,e_i\,\epsilon^k
\end{align}
which equals $e_i\,\epsilon^i$ when
$$
A^i{}_j\,A^j{}_k=\delta^i{}_k
$$
holds.

Now the matrix inverse of $A^i{}_j$ is $A^j{}_k$ which is looks neat but is useless because it is a matrix that is inverse to itself. This only holds when $A^i{}_j$ is the identity matrix.

In short: we need a convention that allows to distinguish $A^i{}_j$ from (the transpose of) its inverse $A_k{}^j$ which is only the case with (1).



Thanks! But it doesn't clear up the confusion for me. Is the logic that I followed (in the last 2 paragraphs of the question) to justify that particular staggered notation for both basis transformation equations fine, or is it not correct? I mean for the dual basis transformation, why can't I just write $\epsilon'^j=A_{\ \ \ k}^j\epsilon^k$ so that $A^i_{\ \ \ j}A^j_{\ \ \ k}=\delta^i_{\ \ \ k}$. OR why can't I write $\epsilon'^j=A_{\ \ \ k}^j\epsilon^k$ and $e'_j=A^{\ \ \ i}je_i$, so that $A^{\ \ \ i}jA{\ \ \ k}^j\epsilon^k=\delta^i{\ \ \ k}$?
